# How to update multiple dropdown value on change of another dropdown in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a table with multiple rows and each row has drop-down to select the value.  All the drop-down have same list. At first, All drop-downs have value selected as per JSON. But what I want to do is to have Another drop-down at the top of page and on change of its value, update all the drop-down values in table.
I have created a AngularJS directive for dropdown.

```
 app.directive('dropdown', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            list: '=dropdown',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/dropdownView.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.height = elem[0].offsetHeight;
            scope.$watch('ngModel',function(){
                scope.selected = ngModel.$modelValue;  
            });
            scope.update = function(rating) {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(rating);
                ngModel.$render(); 
            };
        }
    };
});

<div dropdown="ratings" ng-model="list" ></div>
```

dropdownView.html

```
<div class="dropdown" ng-click="open=!open" ng-class="{open:open}">
<div ng-repeat="rating in list" style="top: {{($index + 1) * height}}px; -webkit-transition-delay: {{(list.length - $index) * 0.03}}s; z-index: {{list.length - $index}}" ng-hide="!open" ng-click="update(rating)" ng-class="{selected:selected===rating}">
  <span>{{rating}}</span>
</div>
<span class="title" style="top: 0px; z-index: {{list.length + 1}}">
  <span>{{selected}}</span>
</span>
<span class="clickscreen" ng-hide="!open">&nbsp;</span>
```

Please help me if someone knows any possible solution.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FpxaRz9BlMUy3m9zqUS8) created from my code

Comment: I want to update the value of all the dropdowns(which are there in table row and are intances of directive dropdown) on change of value of dropdown at the top of the page(which is also instance of directive dropdown0.

Comment: Basically what I intended to do is to call the update function of all the instances and explicitly pass the rating on the value change of topmost dropdown.

Comment: added template for dropdown

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on.. can you create a plunker from here with some data.. https://plnkr.co/edit/KbrmraxAFRXWLATbfYlp?p=preview I have added basic things..

Comment: I have updated the plunkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/FpxaRz9BlMUy3m9zqUS8 Are you able to see the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could solve this:

- **First**, having another `$watch` in your directive which changes `selected` according to `myrating` on the parent.

  ```
  scope.$watch('$parent.myrating', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal) {
      scope.selected = newVal;
    }
  });
  ```

  Here's [**working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zScYhJ8LILso9gbyX9OE?p=preview) of this.
- **Second**, you can use events. Broadcast an event from parent where the `myrating` dropdown is. And, listen the same in child directive(s).

  For this to work, you need `ng-change` firing from the `dropdown` so,

  ```
  <div dropdown="ratings" ng-change="main.myratingChanged(myrating)" ...></div>
  ```

  now, in controller, `broadcast` the event with new `myrating`:

  ```
  vm.myratingChanged = function(myrating) {
    $scope.$broadcast("myratingchanged", myrating)
  }
  ```

  lastly, in the directive, listen to it and updated `scope.selected`:

  ```
  scope.$on('myratingchanged', function(event, data) {
    scope.selected = data
  })
  ```

  Here's [**working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7SPT57Uso2K9ernRu4On?p=preview) of event approach.

---

Using events is always cleaner approach than having to `$watch` and that too from parent. Choose wisely! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the below watch into your controller into in your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FpxaRz9BlMUy3m9zqUS8?p=preview) code and try to execute,

```
   $scope.$watch('myrating', function(){
      angular.forEach(vm.data, function(item){
        item.rating=$scope.myrating;
      });
    });
```